# Ловкое и комфортное использование виртуальных функций для асинхронного выполнения в C++

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, асинхронность, c++14

Для начала, чтобы объяснить, что я хочу, приведу пример классического использования виртуальной функции, а потом плавно перейду к вопросу. Итак, имеем абстрактный класс:

```
class Action
{
public:
    Action();

    virtual ~Action() = default;

    QVariant act(const QList<QVariant> &args) const;

    virtual bool isEnough(const QList<QVariant> &args) const = 0;

    //TODO: virtual constraints();

protected:
    virtual QVariant innerAct(const QList<QVariant> &args) const = 0;


};
```

В классе имеется функция `act`, описываемая, допустим, следующим образом:

```
QVariant Action::act(const QList<QVariant> &args) const
{
    if (!isEnough(args)) {
        throw "ARG_COUNT_ERROR"; //TODO: Exception class
    }

    //TODO: check for constraints

    return innerAct(args);
}
```

Теперь, чтобы создать новое Действие (`Action`), достаточно унаследовать новый класс от класса `Action` и переписать ему `innerAct`, например:

```
class Inc : public Action
{
public:
    Inc();

    // Action interface
public:
//    int argCount() const final;
    bool isEnough(const QList<QVariant> &args) const final;

protected:
    QVariant innerAct(const QList<QVariant> &args) const final {
        return args.at(0).toInt() + 1;
    }
};
```

Теперь достаточно будет вызвать `act` для любого объекта класса `Action`, не уточняя каким именно Действием он является, например:

```
QVariant Command::result(const QVariant &arg)
{
    if (_result.isValid()) { //TODO: if (isPure())
        return _result;
    }

    auto act = action();
    _args.append(arg);

    if (act->isEnough(_args)) {
        return act->act(_args);
    }

    //copy self and return
    _result = QVariant::fromValue(copy<Term>().nodeRef());//carring
    return _result;
}
```

Замечательно!

Теперь, я хочу создать класс, нападобие `Action`, но который выполняет свое действие асинхронно (переходим к вопросу). Это может быть непосредственно создание потока (thread) или вызов функций из других асинхронных библиотек - коннект с сервером, получение удаленной информации по сети, ожидание действий пользователя, показаний датчиков). После окончания вычислений производный класс должен испустить сигнал `complete`, подразумевая, что его поймает пользователь этого класса. Итак, пишем асинхронный аналог нашего `Action`:

```
//Async Action
class Task : public QObject, public Reward::Node
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Task();

    virtual bool isEnough(const QList<QVariant> &args) const = 0;

    void act(const QList<QVariant> &args) const;

protected:
    //должна испустить complete() или соединяться, например, с потоком или с окончание выполнения асинхронной функции (?)
    virtual void innerAct(const QList<QVariant> &args) const = 0; 

signals:

    void complete(const QVariant result);

    //TODO: void error(Error err);?

};
```

Неудобство в том, что в унаследованным от `Task` классе нужно **"не забыть"** вызвать `emit complete` или что-то вроде `connect(_сonnection, received, this, complete)`. Нет ли более ловкого способа (кроме как подробно комментировать функцию) выполнить такую задачу, так, чтобы в производном классе нужно было просто переписать функцию, возвращающую результат или использовать какой-нибудь хитроумный прием или шаблон пректирования?

---

Простейший пример использования:

```
Task *doSomething = new DoSomethingTask();

AsyncCommand *command = new AsyncCommand();

command->setTask(doSomething);
connect(doSomething, &Task::complete, command, &AsyncCommand::onTaskComplete);
```

---

Другой пример (подразумеваемого) использования:

```
//аналог Command::result
void AsyncCommand::result(const QVariant &arg)
{
    if (_result.isValid()) { //TODO: if (isPure())
        return;
    }

    auto tsk = task();
    _args.append(arg);

    if (tsk->isEnough(_args)) {
        connect(tsk, &Task::complete, this, &AsynCommand::onTaskComplete);
        tsk->act(_args);
        return;
    }

    //copy self and return
    _result = QVariant::fromValue(copy<Term>().nodeRef());//carring
    return;
}

void AsynCommand::onTaskComplete(const QVariant &result)
{
    _result = result;
    //что-нибудь еще
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример использования Task, в зависимость от того что нужно есть разные способы сделать это

Comment: Пока не совсем понятно кто именно должен владеть потоком в котором будет выполняется Task::innerAct

Comment: @Arenoros Добавил простейший пример использования

Comment: @Arenoros добавил еще один пример

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но похоже то что вы хотите сделать решается `std::packaged_task` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task

Comment: Хм... В этом что-то есть. Можно в `Task` передавать синхронный `Action` вместо указателя на функцию... Дальше еще не придумал, но подумаю по аналогии с фьючерсами